# How to check whether the folder name exists in file cabinet using suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am creating folder to push monthly invoices through suitescript 2.0. I want to validate whether the current month's folder already created/exists, so that I can skip the folder creation code if it exists. As of now I am getting folder exists error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To verify if folder already exists in File Cabinet, you can create a search on recordType: `folder`.

eg.

```
search.create({
  type: 'folder',
  filters: [
    ['name', 'is', FOLDER_NAME], 
    'and', 
    ['parent', 'anyof', [PARENT_FOLDER_ID]]
  ]
}).run().getRange({ start: 0, end: 1 });
```

You can check [NetSuite's Record Browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2018_1/script/record/folder.html) to get all valid search-filters and columns .

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Avi for the code. It works, you saved my time

Answer (score 1):

You can now use SuiteQL to get this for you.  Use the "N/query" module.

```
let results = query.runSuiteQL({
    query: `SELECT id FROM MediaItemFolder WHERE (IsTopLevel = 'F') AND name = 'Your Folder Name'`
}).asMappedResults()[0]

    if (results) {
        return results.id
    }
```

This will return an object if found for example {"id": 1234}

Use IsTopLevel = 'F' if this folder is in a subdirectory of the file cabinet and IsTopLevel = 'T' if it is in the root folder of the file cabinet.